# ionic build android not working

Tags: installation, ionic-framework

I'm trying to install ionic in my computer and i did all the steps necessary.i even gave the correct environment variables.but i cant build my ionic app for android.when i type ionic build android in the console nothing happens. 
NOTE: i'm trying to build a app which already has android platform added.

These are the paths i have given in my environment variable

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;
C:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools;
C:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools;
C:\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin;
C:\Program Files\nodejs;
C:\Program Files\Git\bin;
C:\Users\CRY$TAL\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Comment: You said nothing happens, so, really, nothing? No error at all?

Comment: yah no errors. but i noticed now when i use cordova build android,it's getting built.

Comment: Odd. Best I can suggest then is filing a bug report. Maybe also make sure your ionic CLI is up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that you need to have a path variable for:

`C:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools\ant`

I know on my Mac I had to make sure i have `tools/ant/` in my PATH before it would build.